# Show posts by category - category ID not working

Tags: wp-query

I have this code which works well except that it doesn't get posts by the category ID.  From the examples I've seen I would expect this to work - am I missing something?

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'category' => 172,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged' => $paged
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
    <h3 class="publication-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h3>
    <p><strong><small><?php the_date(); ?></small></strong></p>
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    <hr>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<!-- then the pagination links -->
<?php next_posts_link( '&larr; Older posts', $wp_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it doesn't work. What examples are using this code?

Let's take a look at [Category Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) of `WP_Query`

There are 5 category parameters:

- cat (int) - use category id.
- category_name (string) - use category slug.
- category__and (array) - use category id.
- category__in (array) - use category id.
- category__not_in (array) - use category id.

There is no `category` parameter on that list, so your parameter is unknown and `WP_Query` ignores it.

So how should it look?

```
...
$args = array(
    'cat' => 172,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged
);
...
```

PS. Also... You shouldn't use `the_title()` in HTML attributes - it won't get escaped properly. So if the title contains quote character, then it will break your HTML code...

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response.  I'm clueless when it comes to WordPress and php, so searching for "show posts by category" came up with people using "category" - but not with WP_Query.  
e.g. <?php global $post; // required
$args = array('category' => 173); // include category 9
$custom_posts = get_posts($args);
foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>     If only my search had come up with those categories!